# Export a plist in a readable fashion

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoding

I have a class following `NSCoding` protocols.

It is designed to store an array, containing objects of a Custom-class type.

I currently can retrieve and view this information in a table view, retrieving and passing the relevant objects.

However, a more accessible, or readable fashion is desirable, As to manually copy this information would be tedious

Is there some way i can retrieve either the entire plist, or take the data from a specific object in it, then send it via email?

or some other export method, perhaps to create a spreadsheet?

Comment: Write a method to present a formatted version. `NSCoding` is not designed to be formatted for presentation.

Comment: Are you asking how to make your data more "human-readable"? Then that's a UI issue. Since we don't know what looks like your data, hard guess, and that wouldn't be a SO issue.